# How to make UIImageView scroll like movie credits?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, scroll, credits

I want to make Credits in my application, so I make that as an image and I am using UIImageView. I want to make that image scroll up from bottom unseen until all image finish and repeat again infinitely.
I can do that with cocos2d but now I am not using cocos2d and only use UIImageView.
Please share some code...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick the long image into a `UIScrollView` and animate its `contentOffset`. Repeat infinitely. If your image is very large, it might be a good idea to split it into several small ones and insert them consecutively.

Comment: [Here's](http://www.aaron.griffith.name/weblog/2011/02/23/scrolling-a-uiscrollview-programmatically/) a blog post with some code.